# How to show the Pop up from when click theASP calender date?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm using ASP calender. I want to show a popup when a user clicks the date,also I want to show the selected date in the popup. I used [this link](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/).

This is my asp calender

```
<div id='basic-modal'>                    
   <asp:Calendar ID="cal" Width="700" OnDayRender="DayRender"  BackColor="white"   runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="cal_SelectionChanged"   >
       <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#C00000" />
       <DayStyle CssClass="basic" />
   </asp:Calendar>
```

this is my pop up form.

```
<div id="basic-modal-content">
<table>
<tr><td>Date:</td><td>
    <asp:Label ID="lblSelectDate" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></td>

</tr>
<tr><td>Message : </td><td>
<textarea id="txtMessage" cols="20" rows="2" ></textarea>
</td>

</tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"   /></td></tr>

</table>
</div>
```

when I click the date it shows popup , but It doesn't  call the  "cal_SelectionChanged" function.

```
protected void cal_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   lblSelectDate.Text = e.ToString();
}
```

So my problem is how to pass the selected date to popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working code..

```
   protected void cal_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        lblSelectDate.Text = cal.SelectedDate.ToString();
    }
```